# Windows installer - run a subsequent time, select "modify" and run specific steps

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an installer built in InstallShield 2014 Premier as a basic MSI project. Part of the UI includes an option screen where the user can select Modify, Repair or Remove. If the user selects modify, I want to collect some information in the UI (or public properties set in the command line) and install shortcuts to a custom folder (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30667275/173225)) then run a DLL custom action. Currently, using the out-of-the-box sequence provided by InstallShield, the custom action gets executed (successfully), and it looks like the create shortcuts is attempted. The installer log shows the set property for the directory holding the shortcuts being executed, and ending up with the expected value. This is an excerpt from the log:

```
...
MSI (s) (B8:E8) [16:08:08:823]: Doing action: UpdateShortcutFolder
Action 16:08:08: UpdateShortcutFolder. 
Action start 16:08:08: UpdateShortcutFolder.
MSI (s) (B8:E8) [16:08:08:824]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ENV_FOLDER property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProduct\PROD Environment\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProduct\TEST Environment'.
Action ended 16:08:08: UpdateShortcutFolder. Return value 1.
...
MSI (s) (B8:E8) [16:08:09:033]: Doing action: CreateShortcuts
Action 16:08:09: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
Action start 16:08:09: CreateShortcuts.
MSI (s) (B8:E8) [16:08:09:034]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiShortcutProperty 
MSI (s) (B8:E8) [16:08:09:034]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiShortcutProperty 
Action ended 16:08:09: CreateShortcuts. Return value 1.
...
```

Is a non-zero return value an indication it succeeded? Other actions that appear to have succeeded return 1 (e.g. set property actions, my DLL custom action). However, the only shortcuts I can find are in the same custom folder as from the original install, and those appear to be unmodified.

It looks to me as if a "modify" just runs through the same steps as the original install (there are no conditions in the InstallExecuteSequence table to indicate otherwise), so I don't see why my shortcuts are not being created. What am I missing?

Comment: Modify is usually to add or remove features - it's a maintenance dialog that doesn't really do anything if you have no features. It's also too late to set properties in the command line because the product is already installed. It looks like you need to break up the setup into features, and installing one of those features would run the custom action and add new shortcuts.

Comment: It does run the custom action DLL though. I'll take a look at using a feature to do that and see if I'm able to get it to work that way, although I need to run it an arbitrary number of times and I'd rather avoid having to deal with multiple instances if at all possible.

Comment: Whether thr CA runs or not depends on the condition, but often people want a CA to run only at install time, not every other time too.

Comment: Ah. So I've got the condition as "NOT REMOVE" which means it will run for anything that isn't an uninstall. I take it there is no corresponding condition for shortcuts (I did try adding the "NOT REMOVE" condition, to no avail)? The condition is empty now.